# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'tuple' selecting data from multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, python-xarray

I am trying to create a numpy array based of two data arrays that I have and select when each equals 1. But am getting an error. Here is both arrays I am trying to select from looks like.

[image]

Here is the code I am using
`ip_zr = np.where((cicep == 1, 1, cicep) & (cfzra == 1, 1, cfzra))`

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: `(cicep == 1, 1, cicep)` is a tuple `(bool, 1, cicep)`

Comment: `np.where` takes 3 arguments, `cond`, `A`, `B`.  `cond` is a boolean array.  For example `np.where(cicep==1, 1, cicep)`.

Comment: Did you spend any time looking at the `np.where` documentation - either before using it, or after getting this error?  And if necessary experimenting with simple cases as shown in the documentation.

Comment: can you explain the actual condition you're trying to apply? it's unclear when you're hoping to get `1`, `cicep`, and `cfzra`.